# Hashed password and createQueryBuilder()

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

This is how I set my password:

```
$member->setPassword(password_hash($_POST['pw1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
```

To check if the password is correct, I can simply use this code:

```
if(password_verify($password, $hashed_pw)) { // $hashed_pw is not set, since this is just an example
    // Do something here
}
```

So far everything is fine.

**The problem**

I am building a query with this method:

```
private function getData($username, $password) {
    // Getting the data
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Members')
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.email = :email')
        ->andWhere('t.password = :password')
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->setParameter('password', $password)
        ->getQuery();
    $result = $query->getResult();

    // Get the name
    $name = $result[0]->getName();

    // Check if query exists
    $result = ($result) ? $name : false;
    return $result;
}
```

Everything will just work fine if the password is not hashed. Well, in my case the passwords are hashed and I have no idea how I can get through this.

I am totally confused, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: As you’re using Symfony, have you considered using the tools provided by the framework? https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer:

```
private function verifyUser($username, $password) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('m')
        ->from('AppBundle:Members', 'm')
        ->where('m.email = :email')
        ->andWhere('m.password = :password')
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->setParameter('password', $password)
    ;
    $member = $qb->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();

    if( $member == null ) {
        $result = null;
    }
    else{
        $result = $member->getName();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Explanation: Renamed your function to `verifyUser`, since that is what it *does*. As you'll see, I've made the code so that when a developer reads it, it should make sense and it'll be easier to support should you have to change the code in the future.

I get the EntityManager and create a QueryBuilder, then create a query whish sets the email & password. Please note that I call `getOneOrNullResult`, which is *important*. If you don't get a result (null), then the password passed in doesn't match what is stored, and this is not the user.

I also set `setMaxResults` to *1*, which should only return *1* result (if it matches), since you should only have one user with this password (hopefully that is the case with your design - if not, you need to rethink the design).

Then I check to see the `$member`, which is one member or null if it didn't match, and set the `$result` to return respectively.

I used `null` as a return value instead of `false`, since `false` is a `boolean`, and it's better design to return `null` in this case.

Hopefully that all makes sense.

---

EDIT #2 - incorporating password hash

```
private function verifyUser($username, $password) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('m')
        ->from('AppBundle:Members', 'm')
        ->where('m.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
    ;
    $member = $qb->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();

     if( password_verify($password, $member->getPasswordHash()) ){
        $result = $member->getName();
    }
    else{
        $result = null;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The above method presumes you store a password hash in you Member Entity, then you get it with the function `getPasswordHash()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and post this answer. Your code looks definitely much cleaner than mine but to be honest I am not very sure that we both get the same result, if you compared your answer with mine. Please note that `password_verify()` is not my own function. This is a PHP existing function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) and basically the point of my issue.

Comment: Yes, I do know that function, but you don't use it properly in your code, and thus my answer. It needs to be called outside the `verifyUser` function and then pass in the `$password` if it matches.

Comment: So that means I would have two functions? The first one would be `verifyUser()` that will return either `$member->getName()` or `null` and the second one would be probably called `getPassword()` that will simply return the hashed password. And then I can use `password_verify()` outside of both functions, right? If so, I would still need two queries but not in the same function. Or am I wrong?

Comment: By the way, do you store a hash in the `Members` Entity? If so, there still might be a better way to handle this. If you do, let me know if there is a `getHash()` or similar method.

Comment: I added an EDIT #2 which should solve the issue. Make sure you don't store passwords anywhere in the clear.

Comment: Now that makes sense to me. Thank you, this looks absolutere great!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just answer my own question. I just needed to create another query:

```
private function getData($username, $password) {

    // Get the PW
    $query_pw = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Members')
        ->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->where('m.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->getQuery();
    $result_pw = $query_pw->getResult();

    if ($result_pw) {
        $hashed_pw = $result_pw[0]->getPassword();
    }
    else {
        $hashed_pw = false;
    }

    // Getting the data
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Members')
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.email = :email')
        ->andWhere('t.password = :password')
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->setParameter('password', $hashed_pw)
        ->getQuery();
    $result = $query->getResult();

    // Verify the password
    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_pw)) {
        // Get the name
        $name = $result[0]->getName();
    }
    else {
        $name = false;
    }

    // Check if query exists
    $result = ($result) ? $name : false;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Suggest you vote to close @Cerad as it's a very poorly written post, and also poorly written code.

Comment: @AlvinBunk If all poorly written posts/code were closed then there would not be much left.  And I am interested in finding out the reasoning behind the two queries.

Comment: Good point @Cerad. I also answer a lot of those types of posts as well. Let's wait and see if you `get any response at all`!

Comment: @AlvinBunk The first query returns the hashed password that I need, so I can use that value into my second query to get the rest of the data that I need. Now that I have the password (given in the parameter) and the hashed password from the database, I can use the function `password_verify()`. I am pretty sure that you can do the same with only one query but since I am very new to Symfony and this is my first project for learning, I didn't know any better way to resolve this problem. If you have a better solution, please feel free to answer and I will mark it as solved.

Comment: @Cerad, you got a response! Thanks for responding Reza. Take a look at my answer. I think it's better, but you can decide. Have a nice day!